# gif animation not working on IE(11)

Tags: internet-explorer-11, animated-gif

I have a gif animation on a load jquery ui dialog. I am using it for stating the progress of a file download using **jqueryfiledownload.js**.

On Internet Explorer(11), When i click on the button that displays the dialog the first time, the animation works, but not on the second time (it works after a refresh);The same manipulation works on chrome.

I have looked through the posts around this  subject, but couldn't find any solution.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think I have the same problem here, after hiding a GIF and making it visible again its animation is not played anymore. Found other people as well: https://www.paulirish.com/2007/animated-gif-not-animating/#comment-1557967935

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me after turning on "Play animations in webpages".

Internet options -> Advanced -> Multimedia -> Play animations in webpages.

Comment: It's already the case, but it didn't work. That's not the problem cauz it's animated the first time loaded, but after that there's no animation unless i refresh the page